# Phaser 3 create tilesprite from dynamic texture

Tags: phaser-framework, phaserjs

[image]I have developed a slot machine in Phaser 3. The reels are essentially tile sprites that rotate during spinning.
When the reels slow down, I would like to load a tile sprite of symbols representing the outcome of the payout engine.
Since I can't load a tile sprite representing the entire reel (each physical reel would contain more than 100 images), the below code I have developed needs to be modified so that instead of loading "symbols", it loads a tile sprite containing predetermined images.

```
function spin_end(obj){
        //stop obj tilesprite at stop position
        obj.y = get_stop('start', obj.id);
        obj.setTexture('symbols');
        //it should be changed in  obj.setTexture('results') how can i create results???
        self.tweens.add({
            targets: obj,
            y: get_stop('end', obj.id),
            duration: 800,
            ease: 'Back.easeOut',
            onComplete(){
                if(obj.id === 4){
                    calculate();
                    is_spinning = false;
                }
            }
        });
        setTimeout(()=>{
            play_sound('Slot Machine Stop '+Number(obj.id+1), self);
        }, 400);
    }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate abit more, it is not clear what you want. why should it be `obj.setTexture(...)`? why is the symbols texture not enough?

Comment: Symbol textures are all the symbols that make up the slot, such as cherry, diamond, etc. So, for example, this slot machine has twelve symbols, and I load a tile sprite on every reel.Of course, the mathematics of the slot machine result in different outcomes compared to what can be achieved with a fixed tile sprite. The slot machine's calculations generate various combinations that may not be present in a static tile sprite.Yes, if the server gives you an outcome such as (cherry, cherry, cherry) for the first reel, you would need to create a tile sprite that contains only those symbols

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand your problem. You can generate reels with tilesprites and randomly set the result, like in the demo below. you don't need to have all combinations pre created.

**Mini Slot-machine - Demo:**

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    scene: { create },
    banner: false
}; 

function create () {
    this.add.text(10,10, 'Click to start')
        .setScale(1.5)
        .setOrigin(0)
        .setStyle({fontStyle: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Arial'});
    
    this.add.text(250 ,10, 'TileSprite')
        .setScale(1.5)
        .setOrigin(0)
        .setStyle({fontStyle: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Arial'});
    
    let graphics = this.make.graphics();
    createReelGraphics(graphics);
    
    this.add.image( 380, 10, 'img' ).setOrigin(0).setScale(1.5);
    
    this.reel1 = this.add.tileSprite(110, 85, 10, 10, 'img').setScale(3);
    this.reel2 = this.add.tileSprite(145, 85, 10, 10, 'img').setScale(3);
    this.reel3 = this.add.tileSprite(180, 85, 10, 10, 'img').setScale(3);

    startSpin(this);

    this.input.on('pointerdown', () => startSpin(this));

}

function startSpin(scene){

    setRandomStartPosition(scene);
    scene.tweens.add({
        targets: [scene.reel1, scene.reel2, scene.reel3] ,
        tilePositionY: '+=100',
        duration: 800,
    });
}

function setRandomStartPosition(scene){
    scene.reel1.tilePositionY = Phaser.Math.Between(0, 8) * 10
    scene.reel2.tilePositionY = Phaser.Math.Between(0, 8) * 10
    scene.reel3.tilePositionY = Phaser.Math.Between(0, 8) * 10
}

new Phaser.Game(config);


function createReelGraphics(graphics){
    let colors = [ 0xFF0000, 0xFF00DC, 0xB200FF, 0x4800FF, 0x0094FF, 0x00FFFF, 0x00FF90, 0x4CFF00, 0xFFD800, 0xFF6A00];
    
    for(let idx in colors){
        graphics.fillStyle(colors[idx]);
        graphics.fillRect(0, (idx * 10), 10, 10 );
    }
    
    graphics.generateTexture('img', 10, colors.length * 10);
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
```

> I hope this demo helps abit, or atleast helps to clarify the problem.

**Update - *Dynamic Reels*:**
*The code might need some improvement.

If you load the sprite with `this.load.sprite(...)` you don't need all the crazy workaround of the `createReelGraphics` function.*

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    scene: { create },
    banner: false
}; 

new Phaser.Game(config);

console.clear();

function create () {
    this.add.text(10,10, 'Reels - Click to rnd create')
        .setScale(1.5)
        .setOrigin(0)
        .setStyle({fontStyle: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Arial'});
    
    let graphics = this.make.graphics();
    createReelGraphics(this, graphics);

    let serverData = rndData();
    this.reels = []
    
    createReels(this, serverData)
    
    this.input.on('pointerdown', () => createReels(this, rndData()) );
    
}

// crazy code, just ignore :)
function rndData(){
    return '1'.repeat(3).split('').map( x => '1'.repeat(4).split('').map( y => Phaser.Math.Between(0,9)) )
}

// create image-textures for the each reels
function createReels(scene, reelData){
    
    for(let reel of scene.reels){
        reel.destroy();
    }
    
    scene.reels = [];
     
    for(let realIdx in reelData){
        let reelKey = `reel${realIdx}`;
        let reelHelper = scene.make.renderTexture(
          {x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 10 * reelData[realIdx].length, add: false}
        );
        
        for(let symbolIdx in reelData[realIdx]){
           let helper = scene.make.image({ x: 0,
                y: 10 * symbolIdx,
                key: 'reel',
                frame: reelData[realIdx][symbolIdx],
                add: false })
                .setOrigin(0);
            reelHelper.draw(helper);
        }
         
        if(scene.textures.exists(reelKey)){
            scene.textures.remove(reelKey);
        }
        reelHelper.saveTexture(reelKey);
        
        scene.reels.push(scene.add.image( 40 + (40 * realIdx), 100, reelKey).setScale(2.5));
    }
}

// If you load the image as a sprite you dont neet all this
function createReelGraphics(scene, graphics){
    let colors = [ '#FF0000', '#FF00DC', '#B200FF', '#4800FF', '#0094FF', '#00FFFF', '#00FF90', '#4CFF00', '#FFD800', '#FF6A00'];
    
    let canvasSprite = scene.textures.createCanvas('reel', 10, 10 * colors.length);
    let ctx = canvasSprite.context;
    
    for(let idx in colors){
        ctx.fillStyle = colors[idx];
        ctx.fillRect(0, (idx * 10), 10, 10 );
        canvasSprite.add(idx, 0, 0, idx * 10, 10, 10);
    }
    canvasSprite.refresh();
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i don't expose the problem clear or maybe ut's not clear to me how tilesprite works. The problem I'm facing is the following: if the server send combination for example all diamonds on all reels on each position :[D,D,D],[D,D,D],[D,D,D],[D,D,D],[D,D,D]. I cannot create this combination starting from the tileprite that i create from the image above, as i don't have 3 sequentials diamonds. isn't it?

Comment: Correct. TileSprite just repeats the same sprite, when the size exceeds the size of the image, but you could generate those reels dynamically. I updated my question, with an example.